# How can I understand the regular point or the regular level set from a geometry view?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am learning manifold, when I see the regular level set theorem, I feel the great power of it. Although this theorem can help us to decide whether a geometry object is a manifold or not, I can't understand it from a geometry view, in the other words , I can't see the regular level set.

How can I see the regular level set ? Or what does a regular level set generally look like?

Comment: There are many theorems in this multivariate context. What is the "regular level set theorem"?

Answer (score 0):

it is (by applying the implicit function theorem) locally a smooth deformation of a set like
$$\{(x_1, \ldots, x_n): x_{i} = 0, 1 < k\le i\le n\}$$ 
This is, of course, just the special case of the zero level of
$f(x) = (x_{k}, \ldots, x_n)$

Comment: How can we deduce the fact you stated from the implicit function theorem?

Comment: @R.Sherlock you already know it's a manifold -- check that proof. Or lookup the proof which shows that a manifold is locally looking like a hyperplane (like the set in my answer).

Comment: Use invertible function theorem?

Comment: @R.Sherlock that's equivalent to implicit funtion theorem.